# unable to launch more tasks in spark cluster

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-blob-storage

I have a 6 node cluster with 8 cores and 32 gb ram each. I am reading a simple csv file from azure blob storage and writing to hive table.

when the job runs I see only a single task getting launched and single executor working and all the other executor and instances sitting idle/dead.

How to increase the number of tasks so the job can run faster. 
any help appreciated

Comment: the overhead of parallelization may be faster than a single task

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that your csv file is in one block. Therefore your data is only on one partition and since Spark "only" creates one task per partition, you only have one.

You can call `repartition(X)` on your dataframe/rdd just after reading it to increase the number of partitions. Reading won't be faster but all your transformations and the writting will be parallelized.